# Can't access parent object from Angular OnInit method?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to attach a custom validator to an Angular Form Control. I am initializing the Form Controls in the ngOnInit method. This validator should check that the field has been given an input (much like Validators.required), but only if a boolean class member `this.shouldCheck` is true.

However, when I attempt to access that class member from the validator function, it cannot find the instance of `this`. I know there are some notorious scoping issues with `this` in Js, but I thought that was solved with Typescript. Not sure how I can check that boolean in the validator.

My component.ts:

```
// this shouldCheck's value is bound to a checkbox on the form
private shouldCheck: boolean = false;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.employeeCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName: [null, [
                this.myRequiredValidator,
                Validators.maxLength(30),
                Validators.pattern('[^<|]+$')]],
            lastName: [null, [
                this.myRequiredValidator,
                Validators.maxLength(40),
                Validators.pattern('[^<|]+$')]]
        }
```

My custom validator:

```
myRequiredValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        // if shouldCheck, perform a basic "required field" validation
        if (this.shouldCheck) {
            return !!control.value ? null : {required: true};
        }
        // else, don't apply validation error
        return null;
    }
```

No matter where I initialize `shouldCheck`, the validator function can't resolve `this` and thus cannot even instantiate the FormGroup.

I tried using a simple null check:

```
if (this && this.shouldCheck) {
    // do validation
}
```

...which allows the FormGroup to be constructed but it never seems to be able to resolve the `this`, even after the form has been initialized. I know ngOnInit runs after the class constructor so that shouldn't have been the issue anyway, but that's all I could think to try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  nameRequiredValidator = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    // if shouldCheck, perform a basic "required field" validation
    if (this.shouldCheck) {
      return !!control.value ? null : {required: true};
    }
    // else, don't apply validation error
    return null;
  }
```

Or

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [null, [
        this.myRequiredValidator(),
        Validators.maxLength(30),
        Validators.pattern('[^<|]+$')]],
      lastName: [null, [
        this.myRequiredValidator(),
        Validators.maxLength(40),
        Validators.pattern('[^<|]+$')]]
    }

    myRequiredValidator(): (AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors | null {
      return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        // if shouldCheck, perform a basic "required field" validation
        if (this.shouldCheck) {
          return !!control.value ? null : {required: true};
        }
        // else, don't apply validation error
        return null;
      };
    }
```